# Console.log debug messages managing

Tags: javascript, node.js

My JS code is usually full of `console.log()` debug messages. Sometimes it is better to turn them off, or to turn off some part of them.

I can, for example, wrap `console.log()` statement in some function with conditions which are defined by some constants. Is it the best way to manage debug output or are more elegant alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping `console.log` into a function works well. But notice that there are also a lot of logging utilities out there for javascript. A little google on "js logger" may yield suitable results.

Answer (score 5):

[Bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) logging module is popular for node.js

Example code `hi.js`:

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
var log = bunyan.createLogger({name: 'myapp'});
log.info('hi');
log.warn({lang: 'fr'}, 'au revoir');
```

Output:

```
{"name":"myapp","hostname":"localhost","pid":40161,"level":30,"msg":"hi","time":"2013-01-    04T18:46:23.851Z","v":0}
{"name":"myapp","hostname":"localhost","pid":40161,"level":40,"lang":"fr","msg":"au revoir","time":"2013-01-04T18:46:23.853Z","v":0}
```

You can then filtering from command lines:

```
$ node hi.js | bunyan -l warn
[2013-01-04T19:08:37.182Z]  WARN: myapp/40353 on localhost: au revoir (lang=fr)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Node.js then [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) is extremely effective as an alternative to console.log()

It's basically a substitute for console.log() except you can enable it at the command line with the DEBUG environment variable based on how you've initialized it in each file.

Let's say I have a project with a couple of files referenced from my index.js file:

one.js

```
var debug = require('debug')('one-one');

var func = function() {
  debug('func');
}
```

two.js

```
var debug = require('debug')('one-two');

var func = function() {
  debug('func');
}
```

You've initialized debug with the name "one-one" in the first file and "one-two" in the second file.

On the command line I can run them like this:

```
node index.js
```

Result: no debug output. However, if I run it like this:

```
DEBUG=* node index.js
```

The both the debug statements will get written out, however, in different colors and with the debug name (one-one or one-two) so I can tell which file they came from.

Now let's say you want to narrow it down a bit more. You could run:

> DEBUG=*-two node index.js

To only get output from debug that's been set with "-two" at the end of the name or

> DEBUG=one-* node index.js

to get everything starting with "one-"

You can also say that you want everything, or a set of things, or exclude patterns or sets. To exclude something you precede it with a dash, an example:

> DEBUG=one*,monkey*,-monkey:banana,-elephant,-chimp:* node index.js

This will include everything starting with "one" or "monkey" and exclude anything called "monkey:banana", or "elephant" or starting with "chimp:"

If you wanted to exclude everything except then:

> DEBUG=*,-pattern1,-pattern2 node index.js

Answer (score 2):

[JS logger](https://github.com/jonnyreeves/js-logger) is quite good and lightweight tool with flixible settings for log messages levels and several predefined logging levels (DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR).